# PHPDoc annotation for tri-state bool return value

Tags: php, phpdoc

I've got a function, which (for example) returns true if access is allowed, false when access is denied, and NULL when access is indeterminate.

What should the `@return` phpdoc be? `bool` doesn't seem to make sense...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
@return bool|null
```

See [here](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.return.pkg.html):

> The datatype should be a valid PHP type (int, string, bool, etc), a class name for the type of object returned, or simply "mixed". If you want to explicitly show multiple possible return types, list them pipe-delimited without spaces (e.g. "@return int|string").

Answer (score 2):

If you want to follow php.net style about the return type. When there is multiple possibility of return data type, they use the type `mixed`.

Example :

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Comment: How the manual describes it is unrelated to PHPDoc, although in this matter it coincides.